# VBA sort code works for one sheet only but not multiple ones

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this code over multiple sheets I get a "Run-Time Error 1004:The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data that you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank":

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 6 To Worksheets.Count

'more code here

Dim ranged As range
Dim lRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

lRow = .range("AJ" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set ranged = .range("AJ2:AJ" & lRow)


.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ranged, _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlDescending, _
                     DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With .Sort
    .SetRange ranged
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End With

'more code here

next i
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work, but what is particularly baffling is that when I try to run it on one sheet only by changing With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i) to With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname") it works fine, but when I put it into the above structure to run over multiple ones it doesn't.The idea is to reverse the order of column AJ starting from AJ2 to the last row with data in it and the length of AJ is different in different sheets. Any ideas?

Comment: Try clearing the Sortfields first.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going about getting your sheetnames is the problem.

You are starting to iterate through i from 6 to Worksheets.count..  With this, assuming you have 10 sheets, you will only iterate through 4 i's before being complete.

The main issue though is that you probably don't have sheetnames that are Sheets(i).  i is a variable here and furthermore, it isn't a string.  So you need to have a string at the other end of the variable you are placing inside Sheets().

I think what you are trying to accomplish is using a LIST of sheet names that are Strings.  Using the variable i as a Long or Integer to iterate through them.  "i" being the NUMBER and name(i) being a String.
 'This example assumes you have 6 sheets.  Declare this at the top with your initial variable declarations.

```
Dim name(1 to 6) As String   
name(1) = "Sheet1"
name(2) = "TotalSales"
name(3) = "MonthlyRevenue"
name(4) = "Sheet 4 Name"
name(5) = "Whatever This sheet is called"
name(6) = "Last Sheet Name"
```

or whatever your sheets are named.  Then when you call Sheets you will use something more like this.

```
For i = 1 to 6
    'YOUR CODE THAT YOU ALREADY ENTERED THAT WORKS WHEN THE SHEET NAME IS CORRECT
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(name(i))
Next i
```